# Angular direct link error on third level domain

Tags: angular

I have deployed an **Angular application** on site *[www.mainsite.xyz](http://www.mainsite.xyz)* it work fine.

Then i need to **install this app on third domain** like this: *[www.subdomain.mainsite.xyz](http://www.subdomain.mainsite.xyz)*
If i navigate with the routing of the app it work fine, but i want expose a **direct link** like this:
*[www.subdomain.mainsite.xyz/register](http://www.subdomain.mainsite.xyz/register)* and always give me **404.**

How i can solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: The page /register should also exist on the third domain and redirect to your application or show your application's register page

Comment: /register exist only on third domain and is up and running. On my third domain i have a button that redirect me to /register and work fine. The problem is if i try to go direct to /register, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you check network activity to see the url's your application wants to go to on the two cases?

Comment: on the first case, when i use the button that is binded with routerlink=/registered , the app use the router service and go directly to the corrispective page.
If instead in go with direct link, that's a GET call to /registered that return me 404

Answer (score 1):

I'm solving the problem using this .httaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```